# Closed-form formula for the differential equation $D^{(n)}(f)=f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $S_n$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ whose $n$th derivative is defined everywhere.

- In terms of the parameter $n$ and arbitrary real constants, is there a closed-form formula for the differential equation $D^{(n)}(f)=f$, where $D$ is the differentiation operator?
- Also, what if we consider functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: You can use MathJax also in titles.

Comment: Characteristic equation is $\lambda^n-1=0$ which is $$(\lambda-1)(\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^{n-2}+\ldots+\lambda+1)=0$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/n}$ ($\omega$ is a primitive $n$-th root of the identity.) Then
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_ke^{i\omega^kz},\quad a_k\in\Bbb C.
$$
In $\Bbb R$ you will have to consider real and imaginary parts.

Comment: "real or imaginary" >> "real and imaginary".

Comment: Can it be shown that this is the only solution?

Comment: Yes, it is standard ODE theory.